# Why does Terraform want to recreate resources that have not changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a some Terraform that provisions resources both in AWS and MongoDB Atlas. I can apply the Terraform and it creates the resources as expected, but then if I immediately run another apply, it says it wants to destroy and recreate many of those resources even though they have not changed.

For example:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name = var.domain
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  name    = "REDACTED"
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id

  alias {
    evaluate_target_health = "false"
    name                   = var.accelerator_dns_name
    zone_id                = var.accelerator_zone_id
  }
}
```

```bash
# module.REDACTED.data.aws_route53_zone.selected will be read during apply
# (depends on a resource or a module with changes pending)
<= data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
      + arn                        = (known after apply)
      + caller_reference           = (known after apply)
      + comment                    = (known after apply)
      + id                         = (known after apply)
      + linked_service_description = (known after apply)
      + linked_service_principal   = (known after apply)
      + name                       = "REDACTED"
      + name_servers               = (known after apply)
      + primary_name_server        = (known after apply)
      + resource_record_set_count  = (known after apply)
      + tags                       = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                     = (known after apply)
      + zone_id                    = (known after apply)
    }

# module.REDACTED.aws_route53_record.record must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
      + allow_overwrite                  = (known after apply)
      ~ fqdn                             = "REDACTED" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                               = "REDACTED" -> (known after apply)
      - multivalue_answer_routing_policy = false -> null
        name                             = "REDACTED"
      - records                          = [] -> null
      - ttl                              = 0 -> null
      ~ zone_id                          = "REDACTED" # forces replacement -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

Terraform claims that the `zone_id` has changed which is why the `aws_route53_record` must be recreated but it hasn't actually changed. The value is the same throughout all of the applies.

Comment: Can you add the plan output for the zone data source to the question?

Comment: where are you storing the state?

Comment: @MarkoE Added the plan output for data.aws_route53_zone.selected.

Comment: @whites11 I'm using the S3 backend.

Comment: I'm wondering about this part for the data source: `depends on a resource or a module with changes pending`. Can you elaborate what has changed so that it affects the data source?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes, that is curious. But the only thing that `data.aws_route53_zone.selected` depends on is `var.domain` which hasn't changed. Could that just mean that it is part of a module that has pending changes?

Comment: Are you creating the zone and then using the data source to query it in the same module? Or in the same run maybe?

Comment: Sort of. Normally, another module in the same run creates the hosted zone then this module reads it in as a data source (I know this is a bad thing but I inherited this code and haven't refactored that part yet). But because of some nameserver nonsense with GoDaddy I have to create the hosted zone manually then `import{}` it. So the hosted zone exists before running `terraform plan`. I tried removing the `import{}` since the hosted zone is now part of the Terraform state, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem, which was pretty insidious because it didn't even have anything to do with the resources described in the question above.

I am invoking two modules from my Terraform where the outputs of the first are used as inputs for the second. Something was changing within the first module which was then marking many (all?) of the resources in the second module as changed. The thing that was changing in the first module was the `container_definitions` of some ECS tasks. The trouble was that this long JSON string contained a sensitive value so the entire `container_definition` was being marked as sensitive thereby making it impossible to see specifically what changed.

I worked around the sensitive string by temporarily using the `nonsensitive()` function so `terraform plan` would show me specifically what changed. This let me see that I wasn't setting certain fields in the `container_definition` like `systemControls`. Because it was unspecified, Terraform was attempting to set it to null but the provider was coalescing null into an empty array instead. This caused the state to appear to be different on each apply since `null != []`.

Explicitly setting `systemControls = []` stopped the ECS task from being recreated on every apply which then caused all of its downstream dependencies from also being recreated.